# How to handle .tsv with uneven quotes?

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to using Python's `csv` module, and I keep running into issues where it can't parse due to lack of escape character and weird data. Here are two examples that cause it to grab multiple lines and break (tab-separated values):

> B 2885192   "Some input
>
> L   30019     "

Both examples break it and get the "no escape char set" error. Here's the main line I use for reading it in:

```
with open (INFO_FILE, "rt", encoding = "latin1") as info:
    info = csv.reader (info, delimiter = '\t')
```

I can't find a solid answer and couldn't figure out the exact way to handle this in the documentation. I'm sure it's as simple as modifying the csv.writer's options. What should I change to accept those as straight strings and not have it try to find end quotes in those cases?

Comment: The code you posted is for writing a CSV file, not reading one.

Comment: CRAP, grabbed the wrong line, editing in a minute.;

Comment: @chepner Fixed, nice catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not specifying `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` for your reader. Try

```
with open (INFO_FILE, "rt", encoding = "latin1") as info:
    info = csv.reader (info, delimiter = '\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    for line in info:
        print(line)
```

Output:

```
['B', '2885192', '"Some input']
[]
['L', '30019', '"']
```

Comment: Derp, should've known, probably looked at my writer the whole time, ugh. Thanks mate.